# How to properly set the ContentMode of an ImageView within a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to set the `contentMode` of a `UIImageView` to be `.top`, that is contained within a `UIView`, but it's not set properly or runs out of the boundary of the `UIView`.

This is what my cell looks like with the red being the container `UIView` with constraints of the `UIImageView`:

[image]
[image]

FYI: The `UIImageView` is a square size because it will be applied with  rounded corners.

What I've attempted to do and the result:

1.

```
thumbnail.contentMode = .top
thumbnail.clipsToBounds = true
thumbnail.sizeToFit()
```

[image]

2.

```
thumbnail.contentMode = .top
thumbnail.clipsToBounds = true
```

also tried adding:

```
thumbnailContainer.clipsToBounds = true
thumbnailContainer.sizeToFit()
```

[image]

What I'm trying to **achieve** is the result of the first screenshot with the `UIImageView` contained inside its container view as seen in the second screenshot.

**UPDATE:**
Based on the comments and answer, I believe some are confused on what exactly I'm trying to do, so I've attached another screenshot of the result I'm expecting :
[image]

As you can see, I want the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to be `.top` such that the top-middle of the image is displayed. You can clearly see the difference between the `contentMode` in the 3rd screenshot, which is `.scaleAspectFit`, versus the `contentMode` in the 4th screenshot, which is `.top` because it is showing the top-middle of the image.

**However**, I would like the `UIImageView` to maintain its original size, as seen in the 3rd screenshot where the `contentMode` is `.scaleAspectFit`, instead of being stretched out horizontally and vertically, as seen in the 2nd screenshot.

I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: as long as there is constraints remove **thumbnail.sizeToFit()**

Comment: @Sh_Khan As shown in code with the 2nd attempt, the result screenshot is not desired

Comment: `contentMode`, `clipToBounds`, auto layout constraints... truly apples and oranges! One has **nothing** to do with the others. I'm not really sure the exact thing you are trying to do, but maybe you should take it a step at a time Get the `UIImageView` working correctly (that's the `contentMode`). Then - and I'm only saying this because a screenshot suggests it - get a table view cell working like you wish. Then? The actual container view. Step-by-step. I think you're doing too much at once.

Comment: You probably want a content mode of `.aspectFit` so that your entire image is show, without distortion, within the image view.  This will leave blank space in the image view if the image size isn't an exact multiple of your image view size. This is what you have achieved in your last example, although through a more complex process.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you want, you need to set content mode to `.aspectFit`, so that image will resize itself in UIImageView's size, keeping its original height to width ratio.